# When creating a digital signature field in iText, is there a way to remove the red flag that appears at the top left of the field?

Tags: itext

I am currently using this code to create a digital signature field in iText.

```
PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.createSignature(writer);
    field.setWidget(new Rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT);
    field.setFieldName(fieldName);
    field.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);
    field.setPage();
    field.setMKBorderColor(BaseColor.BLACK);
    field.setBorder(new PdfBorderArray(0f, 0f, 1.0f));
    field.setMKBackgroundColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
    PdfAppearance tp = PdfAppearance.createAppearance(writer, 72, 48);
    tp.rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);
    tp.stroke();
    field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp);
    stamper.addAnnotation(field, reader.getNumberOfPages());
```

Which creates a digital signature field that looks like this: [image]

Is there a way to remove or alter the appearance of the red flag in the top left corner that says "Sign Here"?

Comment: That *red flag* is a feature of your pdf viewer, not the pdf.

Comment: Only if you use a different PDF Viewer (since this is a feature of the PDF viewer as MKL indicated)